# Rails & Act as taggable, filtering out results with multiple tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable

this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I am using rails 3 with plugin called act as taggable and I like them.

I've been doing a webstore-tutorial from a book called 'Agile Web Development with Rails' (http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Development-Rails-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356549)

My "app" is capable of filtering products with a single tag, but I'd like to be able to list products with selecting multiple tags.

For an example a product called 'Ford Ka' contains tags: 'Ford', 'Ka' and 'red'. When I would click 'Ford' and 'Ka', the catalog would filter me all Ford Ka's.

Some parts of the code at the moment:

**views/tags/index.html.erb:**

```
<div id="tag_cloud">
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), :class => css_class %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**views/tags/show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Photos tagged: <%=h params[:id] %> </h2>
<%= render 'products/catalog', :collection => @products %>
```

**tags_controller.rb**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:show, :destroy]
  def index
    @tags = Product.tag_counts(:order => 'name')
  end

  def show
    @products = Product.tagged_with(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!